# How to deform organic meshes according to parented curves?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, bezier-curves

I'd like to figure out how to use a curve to deform a mesh. This is needed to allow for logical transformation of organic shaped meshes. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a Bezier curve.
2. Line up your plant object with a curve object.
3. Add a **Curve** modifier to your plant.
4. In the modifier, under **Object:**, select your curve.
5. Select your curve in the viewport & go into edit mode.
6. Move the vertices around until you find a good pose.

Hope this helped :)